# Installing Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1 on a system running Windows 7 with Service Pack 1.  However, before the setup begins I get an error message saying "The specified program requires a newer version of Windows."

My understanding is that Visual Studio Community 2015 is compatible with Windows 7 with SP1 installed so I am not sure why I would be getting this error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Open "Properties" of the installer file.

   Usually pressing `<Alt> + <Enter>` keys when installer is selected, should open it or you can right click the installer and select "Properties", which is usually last menu item of the context menu.
2. Go to "Compatibility" tab.
3. Uncheck "Run this program in compatibility mode for", if it is checked.

   If it's grayed out, press button labelled "Change setting for all users" and uncheck it there.

Comment: I have no idea how that happened, but you're a lifesaver.

Comment: awesome! how did you know that was the problem?

Comment: Had the same issue, and had a look at the properties :) for some reason Windows adds it automatically

Comment: @orajestad9 You may want to mark this solution from @Spider as an 'Answer` as you can see many users including me got their issue resolved with this solution.

Comment: I think now this dose not work after windows 10 became non free.

Comment: still doesn't work for me, I have to install window 7 sp1 to make it working